# Iterate two arrays in *ngFor-- IONIC2/Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I  have stored values in  two  arrays to iterate  in a  single ion-list . Billerstatusstate  and  Billerstatusnamelst   are the two  arrays.

I  have tried  the  following  to iterate

```
<ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let stat of Billerstatusstate;let bil of Billerstatusnamelst "  >

  {{bil}} <button round>{{stat}}</button>

</ion-list>
```

and

```
<ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let stat of Billerstatusstate" *ngFor="let bil of Billerstatusnamelst "  >

  {{bil}} <button round>{{stat}}</button>

</ion-list>
```

Its  taking  first  iterated  value  for  both local variable.

Is there  something  am i missing ??

is  there  anyother  way  to  store both  values  in single  array  and split  it  in View  side using  ngFor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  have  followed  this  approach..
I  have   stored   values  in  single  array  instead  of  two arrays  as  it  comes  from  a  single  source.

```
 this.Billerstatusnamelst.push({name:"testname",Status:"Failure"});
```

In  HTML  part

```
 <ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let bil of Billerstatusnamelst "  >

  {{bil.name}} <button round>{{bil.Status}}</button>

</ion-list>
```

Its  worked  for  me..

Answer (score 9):

I could create a pipe to "merge" your two arrays into a single one and then you can iterate over this new array.

Here is a sample:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'merge'
})
export class MergePipe {
  transform(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr = [];
    arr1.forEach((elt, i) => {
      arr.push({ state: elt, name: arr2[i] });
    });
  }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
<ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let elt of Billerstatusstate | merge:Billerstatusnamelst"  >
  {{elt.name}} <button round>{{elt.state}}</button>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I  didnt yet try ur  answer.     I,m  trying  to  save  two  values in array  in  form of  Object  .so  that  i  can  access  based  on  obj.name,obj.status.

Comment: I  will   try  your  approach  as  it  seems  to  be  useful  in  typical  scenarios. @tThierry

Comment: using this approach will the template be automatically updated if one of the array changes?

Comment: This IMO should be the accepted answer, and it seems to me the most "angular" way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

You can leverage the index of the `ngFor` directive to achieve this.

```html
<ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let stat of Billerstatusstate; let i=index">

  {{Billerstatusnamelst[i]}} <button round>{{stat}}</button>

</ion-list>
```

Comment: Instead of  index, i have  to  iterate another  array.

Comment: Does the other array have the same count as the first? And are those arrays related?

Comment: Both  arrays  have  names/status msgs ..Not  related  to index/numbers.

Comment: If they're not related, why on earth do you want to display data from both arrays side by side?

Comment: consider  its  related..  how  to  split   "karthik" + "ONLINE"   value  to  two  different  html elements

Comment: Well, I don't see any problem. This should work as it is.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. You want to show the status of a biller and their name, and the data comes from two different sources? You would need to come up with an array of {name: name,status:status} and iterate through them.

Answer (score 7):

Why instead of doing this

```
<ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let stat of Billerstatusstate;let bil of Billerstatusnamelst "  >

  {{bil}} <button round>{{stat}}</button>

</ion-list>
```

don't you create a single `array` in your code:

```
// I'm assuming they both have the same size
for (var _i = 0; _i < Billerstatusstate.length; _i++) {
    this.singleArray.push({
                         stat: this.Billerstatusstate[_i],
                         bil: this.Billerstatusnamelst[_i] 
                        });
}
```

And then in your page:

```
<ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let item of singleArray;"  >

  {{item.bil}} <button round>{{item.stat}}</button>

</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple array in single array am using

```
    this.termlist = this.result.termlst.$values;
    this.disableterm = this.result.disableterms.$values;
    this.customlist = this.result.customgrplist.$values;
```

single array code

```
 this.totalarrayob =[ this.termlist,this.disableterm, this.customlist];
```

how can i call in html using *ngfor

```
<ion-col col-12 no-padding *ngFor="let list of totalarrayob;let k = index">
    <h6>lorem Ipsum</h6>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>I Term</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
        <ion-note item-right>
          25000
        </ion-note>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>
```